# Is there a way to view any worker_threads that are currently in use in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-worker-threads

I am looking at worker_threads in node and have a simple endpoint that will create a new worker thread and run a CPU intensive script that takes a long time to run.

```
app.get('/test', (req, res) => {
    const worker = new Worker('./number-test.js');
    worker.on('message', (data) => {
        res.status(200).json({data});
    });
});
```

I want to set up a second endpoint that will return information about any workers that are currently active. Is there a way that I can see how many workers are currently in use at any one time?

Comment: There are a couple of problems with this. What happens if 1000 requests hit your endpoint at once? Are you going to spin up a 1000 OS threads? And before you say "I don't have 1000 people looking at this" think carefully about whether you ever programmatically hit endpoints, and how easy it would be to accidentally DDOS yourself. And if this is running in the cloud instead of on-prem, think about what kind of bill you might get before you realized. You probably want a thread *pool*, and the pool should be able to tell you how busy it is.

Comment: Great question. It appears that there is currently no built-in API in Node.js to detect the number of running worker threads, which can make it challenging to create test cases for thread manager modules.